# Set the select option as blank as default in HTML select element

Tags: html

I am required to have no option selected by default in drop down menu in HTML. However, I cannot use:

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Because for this I will have to validate to handle the first option.

Can anyone help me in achieving this target without actually including the first option as part of the select tag?

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to get a blank line.  What do you mean you'll have to do validation?  Just set a check to say if value="" then return false.

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to use radio buttons instead of a dropdown.

Comment: Not a weird requirement at all, in my opinion. I'm in the same boat. I need a 'no option' default, as well. I have several drop downs that aren't required to submit a form. Disabling them in this manner prevents the user from having to make a selection when it's not pertinent. Good question! +1

Comment: Not a weird requirement, if the SELECT had a REQUIRED attribute then having a placeholder label option is a requirement of HTML5 https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-select-element.html#attr-select-required

Comment: @Blazemonger radio buttons are a terrible idea if you have more than 3 or 4. Imagine a dropdown list with 15+ options, or 50 or more? Those have their own design issues in many cases but the issue still stands that radio buttons don't scale well *at all*.

Answer (score 1515, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

`-- select an option --` Will be displayed by default. But if you choose an option, you will not be able to select it back.

You can also hide it using by adding an empty `option`

`<option style="display:none">`

so it won't show up in the list anymore.

**Option 2**

If you don't want to write CSS and expect the same behaviour of the solution above, just use:

`<option hidden disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>`

Comment: [Here is a JSFiddle of the above](https://jsfiddle.net/tcmrp8md/), in case anyone needs it.

Comment: @azerafati as @Rafael_Mori pointed out you can archieve the same by using the "hidden" attribute, so no CSS required. Just pure HTML5 ;) `<option hidden disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>`

Comment: What if i want to be able to select it back? I just don't want it to send anything. Is it possible?

Comment: adding a hidden attribute to the option element did the magic for me! did not expect it to be this easy. thanks

Comment: Be aware, both hidden attribute and display style do not work in IE, even 11. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862242/option-with-hidden-attribute-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Bullseye! Perfect!

Comment: What does blank value do?

Comment: `<option selected disabled hidden  > </option>` worked for me when  I output PHP REQUEST  `var_dump($_REQUEST);  exit() ; `  I didn't got it the value of `select name`

Comment: Nice, didn't think of using `disabled` on the option. Would be great if we could actually do `<option>select something</option>` and have the value passed as `null` when not specified. Very strange that the option's text is passed if the value isn't provided.

Comment: @SebastianThomas Including `value` without setting it explicitly makes it `true` (at least in React), which is a bit hacky. TypeScript throws an error, for example, because it expects it to be of type `string | number | readonly string[] | undefined`.

Comment: Hiding the option (both with display: none and the hidden attribute) will break accessibility with Windows Narrator in scan mode!

Comment: in FF 'hiddent' doesn't hide it, but if you wanted it as "default" it also doesn't work, FF remember. i.e: if i have 2 selectboxes and I "play" with hide/show - if I chose something in select1 and then hide/show select2 - then going back to select1 - it stays on the option I chose .... so whatever solution you found - be aware and test from all angles.

Comment: Tiny things like this can really frustrating to deal with on server side especially when creating dynamic content.

Comment: In Thymeleaf you need to assign a value to `value`, else this error is displayed: `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Attribute "value" is required in "option" tags`

Comment: In React, I used `<option disabled value="" selected={!value}>        Select an instrument      </option>`. It took me a while to figure out that `selected={value===""}` was not what I wanted.

Comment: I ended up using `defaultValue=""` together with `value=""` for the placeholder because this allowed the `required` attribute on the `select` to still work.

Comment: I at first thought it wouldn't work with `<select required>`, but at least in Firefox 123 it tells me to "Please select one of the options" when I try to submit a form with your code in it.   So, thanks!

Answer (score 137):

You could use Javascript to achieve this. Try the following code:

HTML

```
<select id="myDropdown">      
    <option>Option 1</option>     
    <option>Option 2</option>     
    <option>Option 3</option>     
</select>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = -1;
```

or JQuery

```
$("#myDropdown").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

Comment: This solution partially works with Chrome 35: the dropdown does not show any selection when the list of option is invisible, but shows the first option selected when the list of options is made visible. Safari 7 behaves as intended though.

Comment: The interesting thing is: this works with HTML form validation. If you use the `required` attribute on the `select` element and submit without selecting an option the form validation will fail and tell you, you have to make a selection. Therefore I really like this approach. (At least tested in Chrome)

Comment: Does not work (at least in current browsers as of this writing - and unnecessarily relies on javascript.

Comment: As of 2019, only Safari IOS 10 refuses to play ball with this

Answer (score 52):

## Today (2015-02-25)

This is valid HTML5 and sends a blank (not a space) to the server:

```
<option label=" "></option>
```

Verified validity on http://validator.w3.org/check

Verified behavior with Win7(IE11 IE10 IE9 IE8 FF35 Safari5.1) Ubuntu14.10(Chrome40, FF35) OSX_Yosemite(Safari8, Chrome40) Android(Samsung-Galaxy-S5)

The following also passes validation *today*, but passes some sort of space character to the server from most browsers (probably not desirable) and a blank on others (Chrome40/Linux passes a blank):

```
<option>&#160;</option>
```

## Previously (2013-08-02)

According to my notes, the non-breaking-space entity inside the option tags shown above produced the following error in 2013:

> Error: W3C Markup Validaton Service (Public): The first child option
> element of a select element with a required attribute and without a
> multiple attribute, and whose size is 1, must have either an empty
> value attribute, or must have no text content.

At that time, a regular space was valid XHTML4 and sent a blank (not a space) to the server from every browser:

```
<option> </option>
```

## Future

It would make my heart glad if the spec was updated to explicitly allow a blank option.  Preferably using the briefest syntax.  Either of the following would be great:

```
<option />
<option></option>
```

## Test File

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="index.html" method="post">
    <select name="sel">
      <option label=" "></option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 45):

```html
<td><b>Field Label:</b><br>
    <select style='align:left; width:100%;' id='some_id' name='some_name'>
    <option hidden selected>Select one...</option>
    <option value='Value1'>OptLabel1</option>
    <option value='Value2'>OptLabel2</option>
    <option value='Value3'>OptLabel3</option></select>
</td>
```

Just put "hidden" on option you want to hide on dropdown list.

Answer (score 18):

Solution that works by only using CSS:

**A: Inline CSS**

```html
<select>
    <option style="display:none;"></option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**B: CSS Style Sheet**

If you have a CSS file at hand, you can target the first `option` using:

```css
select.first-opt-hidden option:first-of-type {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select class="first-opt-hidden">
    <option></option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 14):

This should help:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

```html
 <form>
 <select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the most modern (html5) way to achieve this requirement, be aware this requires a type=submit button. A type=button with a onclick submit handler doesn't automatically require the user to make a selection.

Answer (score 10):

Just a small remark:

some Safari browsers do not seem to respect neither the "hidden" attribute nor the style setting "display:none" (tested with Safari 12.1 under MacOS 10.12.6). Without an explicit placeholder text, these browsers simply show an empty first line in the list of options. It may therefore be useful to always provide some explanatory text for this "dummy" entry:

```
<option hidden disabled selected value>(select an option)</option>
```

Thanks to the "disabled" attribute, it won't be actively selected anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
<select required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can avoid custom validation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you are trying to do.The best and the most successful way is :

```
<select name='department' required>
   <option value="">None</option>
   <option value="Teaching">Teaching department</option>
   <option value="nonTeaching">Non-teaching department</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it really interesting because I just experienced the same thing not so long time ago.
However, I came across to an example on the Internet about the solution regarding this.

Without any further ado, see the code fragment below:

```
<select>
 <option value data-isdefault="true">--Choose one Option--</option>
 <option>Option 1</option>
 <option>Option 2</option>
 <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

With that, it will stay un-submittable but selectable, anytime. More convenience for User Interface and great for User Experience.

Well that's all, I hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Making it unable to submit but also drawing the user's attention to the dropdown seems redundant, but I like the suggestion

Comment: @lofacture: thanks for the input. actually, the code i wrote was the one i was wanting, but yes as you said, it depends on the needs of the user/owner

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML solution. By the HTML 4.01 spec, browser behavior is undefined if none of the `option` elements has the `selected` attribute, and what browsers do in practice is that they make the first option pre-selected.

As a workaround, you could replace the `select` element by a set of `input type=radio` elements (with the same `name` attribute). This creates a control of the same kind though with different appearance and user interface. If none of the `input type=radio` elements has the `checked` attribute, none of them is initially selected in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel 5 framework and @Gambi `s answer worked for me as well but with some changes for my project.

I have the option values in a database table and I use them with a foreach statement. But before the statement I have added an option with @Gambit suggested settings and it worked.

Here my exemple:

```
@isset($keys)
  <select>
    <option  disabled selected value></option>
    @foreach($keys as $key)
      <option>{{$key->value)</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
@endisset
```

I hope this helps someone as well. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h2>Favorite color</h2>
<select name="color">
<option value=""></option>
<option>Pink</option>
<option>Red</option>
<option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

The first option in the drop down would be blank.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show **please select a value in drop down** and hide it after some value is selected . please use the below code.

it will also support required validation.

```html
<select class="form-control" required>
<option disabled selected value style="display:none;">--Please select a value</option>
              <option >Data 1</option>
              <option >Data 2</option>
              <option >Data 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular (2+), (or any other framework), you could add some logic. The logic would be: only display an empty option if the user did not select any other yet.
So after the user selected an option, the empty option disappears.

For Angular (9) this would look something like this:

```
<select>
    <option *ngIf="(hasOptionSelected$ | async) === false"></option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of (options$ | async)[value]="option.id">{{ option.title }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using `<select multiple>` (combobox; no dropdown), this worked for me:

```html
<select size=1 disabled multiple>
  <option hidden selected></option>
  <option>My Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any empty option at first, try this first line:

```
    <option style="display:none"></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use "..option hidden selected.." as default option

Answer (score 0):

I guess a good idea would be to use the radio buttons, set #1 as default and hide it, give it for example a
`name="init"` and a `value="null"` or whatever, up to you!

this way the radio buttons list has a value definitely, but default of null can be used logically!

I think it's not necessary to elaborate further, since the idea can easily be implemented with `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`

... whereas I think the first one `display: none;` is the better option:

Answer (score 0):

In react, you can give a dummy value (say -1) with select tag as below and same value can be used with this disabled option of yours. (WORKED FOR ME)

```
const nonEmpty = selected[identifierField] || false;

<select
    onChange={(e) => {
      onSelect(
        options.find((option) => option[identifierField] === e.target.value)
      );
    }}
    value={nonEmpty || -1}
  >
    <option disabled value={-1}>Select Option</option>
    {options.map((option) => (
      <option key={option[identifierField]} value={option[identifierField]}>
        {option[displayField]}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`option style="display:none"`

Is bad solution for Tablet: iPad Pro / iOS 15 / Safari
An unnecessary row in the dropdown appears, only for real devices. Doesn`t reproduce on the emulator.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">&nbsp;
    <option>Option 1
    <option>Option 2
    <option>Option 3
</select>
```

Validates in HTML5. Works with `required` attribute in select element. *Can* be re-selected. Works in Google Chrome 45, Internet Explorer 11, Edge, Firefox 41.