# select2 placeholder showing empty option

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

too add  a placeholder in select2 i have to add an empty option tag in the code like this

```
<select id="e2" name="rol_id" >
                       <option><option>
                       {foreach from=$data.roles item=rol}
                       <option value={$rol.rol_id}>{$rol.rol_nombre}</option>
                       {/foreach}
 </select>
```

but when i do that i get this option empty that is selectable
[image]

how can i not show that option but still the placeholder?

Thanks!

Comment: `style="display:none;"` ?

Comment: that still shows the empty option @3rror404

Comment: Maybe this is an option? http://jsfiddle.net/nJ8Vu/

Comment: i dont know if it it because of the select being inside a modal, but the disabled option is not working =( @3rror404

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a syntax error on 2nd line.

```
<option></option>
```

Comment: in the select2 documentation, it says: When placeholder is used for a non-multi-value select box, it requires that you include an empty <option></option> tag as your first option. @Max

Comment: the empty option is fine, but select2 needs to be told the placeholder text - it will then hide the empty option...

Answer (score 8):

It's a late answer, but it can help someone.

I have modal with a select2 input.

We need to add  `<option></option>` for the placeholder to be shown.

**HTML**

```
<select  id="Name">
  <option></option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Brian">Brian</option> 
  <option value="Carl">Carl</option>
</select>
```

If I want the placeholder to appear.

**Jquery**

```
$('#Name').select2({placeholder: 'Select a Name'});

$('#Name').select2('val', '');
```

If I want to see a value on the select2 input:

```
$('#Name').select2('val', 'John');
```

Answer (score 7):

The empty option is actually for placeholder, I solved it using the code below

```
var s1 = $('#select2id').select2({
                    multiple: true,
                    placeholder: "Select values"
                });
                s1.val([' ']).trigger("change");
```

the `s1.val([' ']).trigger("change");` did the trick

Comment: Here's a similar solution which uses pure HTML to prevent it from being clicked, as well as several other approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638053/3196753

Answer (score 2):

leave the empty option and specify the placeholder text either via the data-placeholder attribute on the tag or via a placeholder option when initializing select2.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a line to remove the first "empty" option after loading the options for roles.
You could do it as below using jquery.

```
$("#selectBox option[value='']").remove();
```

Comment: thank you, i tried that but it removes the placeholder =( @sr.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `$('select').select2({placeholder: 'Please select...'});`. Combined with an empty `<option></option>` should do the job ;).

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same problem and simple `<option></option>` didn't work to me.

It seems empty option is inserted but it doesn't allocate any height so it's impossible to reach it.

I solved by just adding a *non-breaking-space* (`&nbsp;`) character (simple space didn't work too):

```
<option>&nbsp;</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit offtop but you may search solution for this:

If you have empty options between every select2 widget option - check your jinja tags and remove `<option></option>` tags if you are using jinja `{% for %}` loop in template.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to put as per the official documentation and it will work :

```
$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');
```