# HTML5 Validation error with select required attribute

Tags: html-select, w3c-validation

Using the following code on `select`:

```html
    <select name="province" id="province" required="required"> 
        <optgroup label="Provinces">
             <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
             <option value="British Colombia">British Colombia</option>
             <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
             <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
             <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
             <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
             <option value="Ontario" selected="selected">Ontario</option>
             <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
             <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
             <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
        </optgroup>
             <optgroup label="Territories">
             <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
             <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
             <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

I need to have values same as the options its just required by guidelines. This code works fine but doesn't pass the W3C validation:

> A `select` element with a `required` attribute and without a `multiple` attribute, and whose size is 1, must have a child `option` element.

What would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default select option as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the following

```
<option value="">Choose</option>
```

Append the above series as first option

- considered valid as the first child element has no content.

Comment: `<option></option>` is no longer valid (Element option without attribute label must not be empty.), gotta have text inbetween like your first `<option value="">OM NOM</option>`

Comment: doing those ways adds an additional validation error

Comment: @Sobasofly Pandiyan's answer should validate, I just tried, `<option value="">just make sure to have text here</option>`

Comment: same one! after adding what marcel posted!  following your way adds an additional validation error!                                     <Element option without attribute label must not be empty>

Comment: Okay then use default text like choose or select inside it. otherwise you will be cornered to remove required attribute.

Comment: @PandiyanCool it works when you add <option value="">Choose</option> before <optgroup>. thanks for the help

Answer (score 25):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (aka validator) here.

> Now it seems you must use a non-breaking space to pass the validator:
>
> `<option value="">&nbsp;</option>`

Yeah I’m not sure when I changed that in the checker. I thought I hadn’t changed anything there in a couple of years but regardless, the checker is conforming to the HTML spec on this, because if you go to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-option-element and read the **Content model** subsection in the head of that section, you’ll see:

> If the element has no label attribute: Text that is not inter-element whitespace.

In HTML, the [definition of which characters can be `inter-element whitespace` characters](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#space-character) includes just U+0020 (space), tab, U+000A (LF), U+000C FORM FEED, and U+000D  (CR).

In other words, HTML essentially considers the non-breaking space character to be Text—not a space character—so putting it inside an `option` element makes that `option` element “non-empty” (as far as the spec is concerned).

So, doing `<option value="">&nbsp;</option>` isn’t really a hack; instead, it’s a perfectly reasonable way (again, as far as the spec is concerned) to make an `option` non-empty.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation and for maintaining this excellent tool!  `<option>&#160;</option>` or `<option>&nbsp;</option>` works too.  It's important that we continue to have a way to show an empty option when we need to force the user to choose something.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes you really just want to have a blank option.   You used to be able to just insert a single space and the w3c validator would accept it.   This used to work:

```
<option value=""> </option>
```

Now it seems you must use a non-breaking space to pass the validator:

```
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
```