# What event to handle choose option from <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an select with options which are loaded by ajax. After that user chooses option and additional data is pulled from ajax. 
Of course at least one these options is selected as soon as select is filled with options so when I listen for change of this option:

```
$('article select.fetchedPosts').on('change', function () {
//do stuff and things
})
```

and user wants to fetch data for first (by default already selected) option the event is not firing because nothing has changed...
So is there any event in JS which would fire everytime user chose something from select, using keyboard or mouse?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but onChange event works as you described and it should works for you. See demo here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: You could use a default blank option, see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do default instead of Option 1 Which option as "Select Option", and the user will have to replace the selection.

```
<select>
  <option>select option...</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`change` should be the correct event. According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> When the user commits the change explicitly (e.g. by selecting a value from a 's dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a date from a date picker for  [...]

There's actually an example `select` at the end of the page, where you can experiment clicking options or selecting with your keyboard, and each time it fires the event.

It may also change depending on your browser:

> Different browsers do not always agree whether a change event should be fired for certain types of interaction. For example, keyboard navigation in  elements never fires a change event in Gecko until the user hits Enter or switches the focus away from the

Comment: I check in Chrome and Fox - when I choose chocolate for first time it's not firing. I think I should do the blank  "select option"