# default select option as blank mvc razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want `null option selected` displayed as `--Select--` by default in my dropDown. I'm trying to do it like this

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="EducationId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.educations, "Id", "Name"))"><option>--Select--</option></select>
```

It loads dropdown perfectly with `--Select--` option selected but it does not make its value `null`. And when I try to get it value without selecting any option doing this

```
$('#EducationId option:selected').text()
```

It returns string having `--Select--`

> But I want it to return null

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638053/2660342) by adding `disabled selected` but according to its statement, once I select any option, it does not allow me to select that first option again. but in my case, this dropdown is optional and user can un-select any selected option.

> How could I make this dropdown optional?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: why not use $('#EducationId option:selected').val()

Comment: $('#EducationId option:selected').text() will return the text in the option tag. As @Usman pointed out, use $('#EducationId option:selected').val() to get the actual value of that option tag.

Comment: I've tried `val()` but it also returns --Select--

Comment: `<option value="">--Select--</option>` and then `var selected = $('#EducationId'),val();` would return `null` if the first option is selected.

Comment: no, it returns empty string. @StephenMuecke

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: I don't know..but I checked its type `typeof($('#EducationId').val())` and it returns string...

Comment: It posts back as `null` (and if property `EducationId` is nullable, then it will be bound to `null` and its its not nullable, a `ModelSate` error will be generated.

Comment: I'm not handling it on a post back request.. I'm validating it in javascript.. there I always find it as string.. even the solution I'm doing right now is also return -1 as string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `educations` is a bunch of items you are presenting to the user to select from. Simply add another item to it like this (I am assuming it is called `Education`):

```
Model.educations.Insert(0, new Education{Id = -1, Name = "--Select--" });
```

Then check if that item has been selected and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: getting idea from your answer, I handled my issue with minor change.. 
    `asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.educations, "Id", "Name"))"><option value="-1"></option>`

and to check for null/ not selected value
     `if ($('#EducationId').val() == '-1') `

Comment: I got idea from you.. so here I'm marking it as answer. Thank you :)