# adding none option in html dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make "none" option as default before select an option from dropdown. My code is given below.

```
<select name="SelectFlow" id="Flow"> </select>  

<script>
var select = '';

for (i=0;i<=100;i++){   
    select += '<option val=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';
}

$('#Flow').html(select); 
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default select option as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank)

Comment: Of course, it is a duplicate, but all the people looking for a solution will formulate their problem in another way, and perhaps find the duplicated question faster than the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Add one line into your javascript code:

```
<select name="SelectFlow" id="Flow"> </select>  

<script>
var select = '<option selected="selected">None</option>';

for (i=0;i<=100;i++){   
    select += '<option val=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';
}

$('#Flow').html(select);
</script>
```

See: [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)