# Default blank option on <select> for Safari

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to make a `<select>` where the first `<option>` is empty, it is not visible in the dropdown and not selectable.

I've been researching for like 4 hours. I saw so many working options but the thing is that none of them (or at least what I've found) are working on Safari.

This is my code:

```html
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="subindustryName">
   <option *ngFor="let subindustry of subIndustries" [value]="subindustry.value"> 
      {{subindustry.label}}
   </option>
</select>
```

I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: can you please share code

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default select option as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank)

Comment: I've tried pretty much everything from those posts and it dosen't work for me

Answer (score 2):

would this work for you? you can set style properties for an option and disable the field so it's not selectable anymore. this question seems to have been answered with another post. [default empty option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank).

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected value style="display:none"></option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">three</option>
  
</select>
```

Comment: I've tried this, and this is the best I can do.
When it shows the dropdown at first the option still appears there and I don't like that

Comment: Without disabled actually. with disabled it doesn't even make the select blank.
<option hidden selected> only makes it blank but it's still selectable in the dropdown

Comment: not sure, it's probably something with safari. most users probably wouldn't notice or care.

Comment: it's actually for a client, and he insist

Comment: I guess you can make your dropdown using css and hover selects and use a bit of javascript to set a hidden field. it's a lot more complicated then the option field but it should accomplish the same thing. It's quite a bit worse since this type of dropdown won't work without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Just add option with value undefined to force angular to select that value. like below

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="subindustryName">
    <option value="undefined"></option>
    <option *ngFor="let subindustry of subIndustries" 
    [value]="subindustry.value">{{subindustry.label}}</option>
</select>
```

and with if you want to it to be not selectable then add 'disabled' attribute with that.

**EDIT AS PER COMMENT**

so whatever you pasted in question should work.
Here is my code snippet which is working..

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select id="gender" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userModel.gender" name="gender" required >
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just try with template driven approach for 'subindustryName' and check.

Comment: ok, so <option value="undefined"></option> works fine, the same as <option hidden selected> and when I add the disabled attribute it's still shown on the dropdown bar until I select another value. This is the best case I can get, but I it would be great if it wouldn't be visible on the dropdown at first.

Comment: just edited my answer . try template driven approach and check if it works. and if it works then you can check what is the issue with reactive approach

Answer (score 0):

if you use like.

```
<select>
    <option> Select Option </option>
    <!--  replace above code with --> 
    <option value='' selected> Select Option </option>
</select>
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option disabled selected value>Select Option</option>
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
```

In both Safari and Chrome, default disabled selected value is this.