# How do i give name in select tag <select> in vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create selected dropdown with vue JS 
The code following :

```
<select v-model="selected"> IDR
   <option value="IDR"><strong>Mata Uang</strong> </option>
   <option>Rp Indonesia Rupiah</option>
   <option>US$ U.S.Dolar</option>
</select>
```

So the question is how do i give name select tag? i try to add "IDR" but still can't show the "IDR" text
How to solve this or any suggestion about this?

Comment: Seeing on how everyone is just guessing on your intentions, you need to clarify what you mean by "how do i give name select tag?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, wether i understand the question correct. You can add some `name` or `ref` attribute to the select either via HTML or the [vue api for ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

```html
<select v-model="selected" name="IDR" ref="IDR">
   <!-- Options -->
</select>
```

However, if you want to display a default option to the user then have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638053/8211893).

Answer (score 0):

The below code helps to get name and value:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
          data (){
            return {
              selected:null
            }
          }, 
  methods:{
    onChange(e){
      console.log("name:" + document.getElementsByTagName("select") 
[0].getAttribute("name") + "  value:" + e.target.value  )
  
   
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <select @change="onChange" v-model="selected" name="IDR"> 
        <option value="IDR"><strong>Mata Uang</strong> </option>
        <option>Rp Indonesia Rupiah</option>
        <option>US$ U.S.Dolar</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```