# dropdown menu for form - with 'required' code not working

Tags: html

I am creating a form with a dropdown menu but the problem is, you could select the ‘please select’ option which I don’t want

```html
 <p class="text-grey">Membership type? (please select)</p>
    <select class="city-town font"  name="eventtype" required>
    <option>Bronze</option>
    <option>Silver</option>
    <option>Gold</option>
    </select>
```

So I created this instead so the ‘please select text is greyed out’ 
But then the ‘required’ part of the code won’t work, not sure why?

```html
<p class="text-grey">Membership type? (please select)</p>
    <select class="city-town font"  name="eventtype" required>
    <option disabled="" selected="" value="0" >Please Select</option>
    <option value="">Bronze</option>
    <option value="">Silver</option>
    <option value="">Gold</option>
    </select>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your option tags are wrong.`<option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default select option as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank)

Answer (score 0):

**Credit where credit's due.** The original post came from @Gambit on [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank) Please upvote his solution.

The submits will always register a field that is selected on a `<option>` element even when it is disabled. I don't know exactly why that is, but it is there.

Instead of having the `selected` and `disable` attributes set a `hidden` attribute on the element. It requires no styling and makes the `<option>` greyed out, un-selectable and with no default value set.

So the code written down here:

```
<option disabled="" selected="" value="0" >Please Select</option>
```

Should be written as:

```
<option hidden value="">Please Select</option>
```

Check it out in this example:

```html
<form>
  <label for="eventtype">Choose Membership</label>
  <select id="eventtype" class="city-town font" name="eventtype" required>
    <option hidden value="" >Select Membership</option>
    <option value="bronze" >Bronze</option>
    <option value="silver" >Silver</option>
    <option value="gold" >Gold</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Choose">
</form>
```