# option with hidden attribute not working in IE

Tags: html, angular7

The following code should display dropdown with some options where first of them is only used as a dropdown's title - it's disabled and should not be present on the list of options. However it's not working in IE (working fine in Firefox), "Select value" is visible (but as disabled option) on the list.

```
<select>
 <option [ngValue]="undefined" hidden disabled>Select value</option>
 <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value">
   {{value}}
 </option>
</select>
```