# Why does jQuery option:selected return first option when nothing is selected

Tags: jquery

When I use `alert($("select").find("option:selected").val());` on a select that has no option selected, jQuery alerts the value of the first element within the select.

Why is that, and how do I get my expected return value of `''` or even `undefined`?

Link to fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzgb03mu/)

```js
alert($(".select").find("option:selected").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if you want default select option as blank this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good question. After investigating the source code, it seems that jQuery will return the value under the selectedIndex and it is 0 in both the cases below

My recommendation is to have a "Please select" without value - you can disable it so it is not sent to the server.

That also means your select will trigger onchange when the first actual value is selected AND HTML5 validation will make a `required` work

```js
console.log($(".select1 option:selected").val(),
            $(".select2 option:selected").val());
console.log($(".select1")[0].selectedIndex,
            $(".select2")[0].selectedIndex);  
$(".select1 option").each(sel => console.log(sel.defaultSelected) )
$(".select2 option").each(sel => console.log(sel.defaultSelected) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select1">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>

<select class="select2">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your first option is selected as default then create an another `option` and set attributes of `selected` and `disabled`, Because user will not select that option

```js
alert($(".select").find("option:selected").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option selected disabled value="">Select Any Item</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that can't be correct. The first value is not selected by default. If that would be the case and you post a form like that the results would be unusable.

Comment: Yes it is selected by default