# How to put a title in a drop down list?

Tags: html, angular

The dropdownlist is white/empty. I would like to put a title for example `Choose`.

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2061.png)

I tried adding `<optgroup label="Choose">/ </optgroup>` but I want the title to be in the input before that the user clicks on the dropdown.

How to do this?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" class="form-select" style="width: 10%">
  <optgroup label="Choose ">
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here is a reproduction on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqn8te?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Thanks

Comment: `<option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>` or look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: The `<select>` tag by default has the first option selected and it's never blank...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this -

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" class="form-select" style="width: 10%" placeholder="Choose">
    <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

This answer is copied partially from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638053/18254155) answered by [gam6itko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470717/gam6itko)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" class="form-select" style="width: 10%" placeholder="Select a value">
  <option selected disabled value="">Select a value</option>
  <option value="Y">Yes</option>
  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```