# How do I not include 'none' in a HTML email if the user hasn't made a dropdown selection?

Tags: html, forms

I was learning how to use the select tag in HTML to create dropdowns. And then I found out that dropdown selections could be sent as an email. After some experimenting with the tag, I figured out that I couldn't 'not include' the 'None' keyword in my email if the user hadn't made a dropdown selection. This was very frustrating.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="mailto:test@gmail.com">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="None">None</None>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <label for="bike">Choose a bike:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="None">None</None>
    <option value="bike1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="bike2">Saab</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

(Code Credits: [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select))

Basically, when I make 1 out of the 2 dropdown selections and leave the other as none when I click submit the label with the value None is included

For example, If I choose Audi for Car dropdown selection and none for Bike selection, in the mail it's displayed as:
*cars=volvo
bike=None*
or something like that. How do I not include 'none' in the email if the user doesn't make a selection for that particular label?

*Apologies for not framing the question clearly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

required the select tag and empty the first element to set as a placeholder

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" required>
    <option value="">None</option>
```

complete code will be like follows:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="mailto:test@gmail.com">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars" required>
    <option value="">None</None>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <label for="bike">Choose a bike:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars" required>
    <option value="">None</None>
    <option value="bike1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="bike2">Saab</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

i hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: It now displays it as car=audi, bike=

Comment: It doesn't include the 'None' as it did before. But how do you get rid of the empty 'bike='? In that way, if the user hasn't made a selection, both the 'None' and the the label wont be displayed in the email

Comment: Btw, I didn't want to use 'required' statement because I don't want to force the users to make a selection

Comment: you are a beginner. You have to start learning from w3school I think that's best for you.

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks for all your help. Btw, I found the solution 
 here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank

Comment: For your question, the answer is when you add a value attribute to an option tag which is <option value="sample">Test</option> then it takes the value "sample" and if you use the tag without value attribute like this <option>Test</option> then it takes "Test" as value. in the above you used a value attribute so you must have something on it otherwise value will be empty. i hope this will clear your mind.